# How to get a ReadOnlyCollection<T> of the Keys in a Dictionary<T, S>

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, collections, c#-2.0

My class contains a `Dictionary<T, S> dict`, and I want to expose a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` of the keys. How can I do this without copying the `Dictionary<T, S>.KeyCollection dict.Keys` to an array and then exposing the array as a `ReadOnlyCollection`?

I want the  `ReadOnlyCollection` to be a proper wrapper, ie. to reflect changes in the underlying Dictionary, and as I understand it copying the collection to an array will not do this (as well as seeming inefficient - I don't actually want a new collection, just to expose the underlying collection of keys...). Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Edit: I'm using C# 2.0, so don't have extension methods such as .ToList (easily) available.

Comment: Part of the problem is that ReadOnlyCollection<T> is an IList<T>, not just an ICollection.

Comment: This sucks I hate the fact that ReadOnlyCollection doesn't support IEnumerable<T> or at least ICollection<T>.

Comment: @Shimmy: ReadOnlyCollection<T> *does* implement IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: no, you can't initialize a ReadOnlyCollection<T> from anything but `IList<T>`.

Comment: True; I misunderstood what you meant by "support". The contructor takes an IList<T>; the ReadOnlyCollection<T> implements  IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T> and the non-generic versions of the interfaces.

Comment: @Shimmy: The name `ReadOnlyCollection` is unfortunate, IMHO; there should have been separate `ReadOnlyListView<T>` and `ImmutableList<T>` classes.  It's not possible to make a read-only `IList`-compatible *view* of a dictionary's keys; it would be possible to make an immutable list from the *present contents* of the keys, but that's a distinct operation.

Comment: @Shimmy: If there had been an `ImmutableList<T>` derived from `ReadOnlyListView<T>`, the constructor of the latter could have accepted an `IEnumerable<T>`, and code which used that would know that it was taking a snapshot.  Overloading a constructor for the `ReadOnlyListView<T>` type to accept things for which it couldn't return a live view would not be good, but allowing code to select snapshot vs live-view semantics via a constructor choice would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to use ReadOnlyCollection<T>, the issue is that the constructor of ReadOnlyCollection<T> takes an IList<T>, while the KeyCollection of the Dictionary is only a ICollection<T>.

So if you want to wrap the KeyCollection in a ReadOnlyCollection, you'll have to create an adapter (or wrapper) type, implementing IList<T>, wrapping the KeyCollection. So it would look like:

```
var dictionary = ...;
var readonly_keys = new ReadOnlyCollection<T> (new CollectionListWrapper<T> (dictionary.Keys)
);
```

Not very elegant though, especially as the KeyCollection is already a readonly collection, and that you could simply pass it around as an ICollection<T> :)

Comment: hmm. So you're saying it's an ICollection, and it's read-only, but it's not a ReadOnlyCollection. :/ How inconvenient...

Comment: @JoelinGö: A better name for `ReadOnlyCollection` would have been named `ReadOnlyListView<T>`.  If it had been given that latter name, it would have been obvious why a read-only implementation of `ICollection<T>` wouldn't qualify.

Answer (score 5):

DrJokepu said that it might be difficult to implement a wrapper for Keys Collection. But, in this particular case, I think the implementation is not so difficult because, as we know, this is a read-only wrapper.

This allows us to ignore some methods that, in other case, would be hard to implement.

Here's a quick implementation of the wrapper for Dictionary.KeyCollection :

```
class MyListWrapper<T, TValue> : IList<T>
{
    private Dictionary<T, TValue>.KeyCollection keys;

    public MyListWrapper(Dictionary<T, TValue>.KeyCollection keys)
    {
        this.keys = keys;
    }

    #region IList<T> Members

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        IEnumerator<T> e = keys.GetEnumerator();
        int i = 0;
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            if (e.Current.Equals(item))
                return i;
            i++;
        }
        throw new Exception("Item not found!");
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            IEnumerator<T> e = keys.GetEnumerator();
            if (index < 0 || index > keys.Count)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            int i = 0;
            while (e.MoveNext() && i != index)
            {
                i++;
            }
            return e.Current;
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection<T> Members

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return keys.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        keys.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return keys.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return keys.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return keys.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This might not be the best implementation for these methods :) but it was just for proving that this might be done.

Comment: You forgot to call Dispose on the enumerators in IndexOf and the Indexer. Furthermore the call of Equals on e.Current can result in a NullReferenceException. Also it is not wanted by Microsoft to throw an Exception in IndexOf, return -1 if not found.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using C# 3.0 and you have:

Dictionary< T,S > d;

Then

ReadOnlyCollection< T > r = new ReadOnlyCollection< T >( d.Keys.ToList()  );

You will also need to import the System.Linq namespace.

Comment: nope, this will not reflect changes to the undelying Dictionary; see jb evain's answer.

Comment: The original poster said they were using C# 2.0, not 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot to that direcly as far as I know as `KeyCollection<T>` does not expose anything that would allow you to do this easily.

You could, however, subclass `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` so that its constructor receives the dictionary itself and override the appropriate methods so that it exposes the Dictionary's items as if they were its own items.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, in .NET 4.6, the `KeyCollection<T>` implements `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, so if you use that interface, you can still reflect changes to the dictionary, still get O(1) contains*, and because the interface is covariant, you can return `IReadOnlyCollection<some base type>`

*`Enumerable.Contains<T>` does an `as` cast on the `IEnumerable` to forward it to `ICollection<T>.Contains` if available. See "remarks" on Enumerable.Contains: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains#system-linq-enumerable-contains-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-0).  `Dictionary.KeyCollection` also implements `ICollection<T>`

Comment: [`IReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1?view=netcore-3.1) does not provide `.Contains(T)`. If you call `.Contains(T)` on an `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, you are getting the O(n) [`Enumerable.Contains<T>(T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netcore-3.1). This is confusing because [`ICollection<T>.Contains(T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.contains?view=netcore-3.1) exists.

Comment: Well, here's the interesting thing: we'd be _exposing_ it as `IReadOnlyCollection`, but the object _itself_ is actually still the `KeyedCollection`, which does implement `ICollection`. 
Importantly, `Enumerable.Contains` does check for `ICollection` and uses it if available (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,f60bab4c5e27a849). So, I'd have to double check, but it should work because the `as` should find the `ICollection`.  I could have been more descriptive about this in the answer.

Comment: If you are accessing it as a concrete type, then you will call one of the methods on the concrete type using the method hiding rules. Overload resolution on a concrete type will never see interface members. You may happen to have concrete members with the same names and signatures as interface members, but you will only actually access interface members if you access the object through the interface (such as by declaring a variable whose type is that interface and assigning the object to that variable first).

Comment: You need to understand how interface implementation works in csharp for things to make sense. “implicit interface implementation” basically just means the csharp compiler automatically generates “explicitly interface implementations” which point directly to your public members. When accessing a concrete type, you never can see interface members (including explicitly implementations) because they are not part of the public/visible surface of the concrete type itself.

Comment: You're misunderstanding what I'm saying.  As an example, imagine a class that has a private List<T>.  It has a public IEnumerable property which returns that List.  You're safe, right, caller can't modify it?  No.  The caller could cast it back to List<T> (the apparent type is IEnumerable but the actual type is List<T>), and manipulate it.

Comment: Similarly, Dictionary.KeyedCollection implements both IReadOnlyCollection and ICollection.  Hence, you can directly return it as IReadOnlyCollection.  However, its actual type is still Dictionary.KeyedCollection.  The caller of the property could cast it back to Dictionary.KeyedCollection if they really wanted.  But what is important for our purposes is that the `as` cast in Enumerable.Contains (to ICollection) as I linked previously will succeed because the actual type is still Dictionary.KeyedCollection, even if the apparent type was merely the IReadOnlyCollection interface.

Comment: Yes, `Enumerable.Contain` does have optimizations which involve dynamic casts. I am disappointed that it even documents that in its interface. It’s a harmless optimization, but it is inconsistent with the interface. Anyways, if you are consuming `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`, you mayn’t rely on the possibility that the caller passed you something which can be successfully cast to `ICollection<T>`. If you need the interface `ICollection<T>`, then consume it instead of `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. The fact that it was O(1) for you was just luck ;-).

Comment: It's not luck when everything is spelled out in the documentation.  It's a solution that fulfills the requirements and does not require creating any new classes.

Comment: If you have an interface that accepts/consumes `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, you cannot assume that calling `Enumerable.Contains<T>(IEnumerable<T>,T)` on that value will be O(1). Your method’s runtime will be O(n) because big-Oh notation documents the worst case behavior as it indicates a maximum bound. That is, unless if you propagate the documentation from `Enumerable.Contains<T>(IEnumerable<T>,T)` to your method’s own documentation. Anyway, it’s not something the compiler is going to enforce since you’re not allowing it to.

Comment: In practice, the the .NET collections often require contracts beyond what the compiler can enforce, because they weren't perfectly thought out. `ICollection<T>.Contains` itself is never specified to be O(1) either.  `ISet` and `IReadOnlySet` came along too late and there are often gaps, and as you've demonstrated that frequently requires assumptions/documentation that some `ICollection<T>` has O(1) contains.

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but this will do it

```
Dictionary<int,string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
...
ReadOnlyCollection<int> roc = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>((new List<int>((IEnumerable<int>)dict.Keys)));
```

Comment: This will not reflect changes to the underlying Dictionary.