# How to make a readonly C# List by non declaring its set attribute

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a `List<string> myList` in my class that I want to be readonly for the class users.

```
List<strign> myList {get;}

private void SetListValue()
{
    myList = new List<string>();
    myList.Add("ss");
}
```

Like this I thought I could set the `myList` value inside my class in my private members and make it readonly for the class users. But I realised that declaring it that way I'm unable to set any value.

Comment: You add an accessor to the set.  ie: { get; private set; }

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you want to prevent clients from changing the `List` reference, or do you want to prevent clients from adding items to or removing items from the list?

Comment: I want to prevent clients changing the List reference.

Comment: @senyorToni: If you just want to avoid clients from assigning new lists altogether, but can still modify using `Add`, `Clear`, `Remove`, etc, then feel free to use a public getter with private setter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[List<T> readonly with a private set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749021/listt-readonly-with-a-private-set)*.

Comment: Alternative duplicate: *[Best practice: How to expose a read-only ICollection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285323)* (from 2008)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
public List<string> myList {get; private set;}
```

This will let you set it inside your class, but not outside. Note that this will not stop external clients updating your list, only the reference to it.

Comment: This will prevent consumers from replacing the entire `myList`, but they can still add/remove/modify the list contents

Answer (score 5):

A private setter for a List, Collection, etc. means that the entire list cannot be replaced by consumers, but it does nothing to protect the public members of the list.

For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public IList<string> MyList {get; private set;}

  public MyClass()
  {
     MyList = new List<string>(){"One","Two", "Three"};
  }
}

public class Consumer
{
  public void DoSomething()
  {
      MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

      myClass.MyList = new List<string>(); // This would not be allowed,
                                           // due to the private setter

      myClass.MyList.Add("new string"); // This would be allowed, because it's
                                        // calling a method on the existing
                                        // list--not replacing the list itself
    }
}
```

In order to prevent consumers from altering the members of the list you could expose it as a Read-only interface, such as `IEnumerable<string>`, `ReadOnlyCollection<string>`, or by calling `List.AsReadOnly()` within the declaring class.

```
public class MyClass
{
  public IList<string> MyList {get; private set;}

  public MyClass()
  {
     MyList = new List<string>(){"One","Two", "Three"}.AsReadOnly();
  }
}

public class Consumer
{
  public void DoSomething()
  {
      MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

      myClass.MyList = new List<string>(); // This would not be allowed,
                                           // due to the private setter

      myClass.MyList.Add("new string"); // This would not be allowed, the
                                        // ReadOnlyCollection<string> would throw
                                        // a NotSupportedException
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: exposing it as `IEnumerable<string>` will _not_ prevent modifications to the underlying list. Users can still cast to `List<string>` and make changes. (but it's easy enough to change it so instead of directly returning it to use `yield return`, or as you suggest, `List.AsReadOnly()`)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair true, `AsReadOnly()` is the better of the options

Comment: I think you may need to take a second pass on your code. I think you got some type declarations/initializations mixed up and won't compile. And likely `MyClass` will want to privately make modifications to `MyList` in your second example.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll skim it over again--it was intended to be more pseudo-code than copy-and-compile

Answer (score 0):

You want a public property with a private setter. As below.

```
public List<string> myList { get; private set; }
```