# When to expose an IEnumerable instead of an ICollection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

```
public class Order
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 [DisplayName("User")]
 public long UserId { get; set; }
 [ForeignKey("UserId")]
 public virtual User User { get; set; }
 public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

With `IEnumurable`

```
public class User
{
 public int Id{get;set;}
 public virtual IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; } 
}

public User GetWithOrders()
{
 var myUser=UserRepository.GetByEmail("email@email.com");
 myUser.Orders=OrderRepository.GetByUserId(myUser.Id);
 return myUser;
}
```

With `ICollection`

```
public class User
{
 public int Id{get;set;}
 public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } 
}

public User GetWithOrders()
{
 var myUser=UserRepository.GetByEmail("email@email.com");
 return myUser;
}
```

I don't have lazy loading using `IEnumerable` for a navigation property. Therefore, I have to get the orders for this user with another query.

I have navigation with `ICollection`. So I can reach orders from user. This seems cool. But then I can add new orders to the user in the Controller without using service or repository.

It's kind of manipulating data on controller level. Is this anti-pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But [with `ICollection`] I can add new order in Controller without using service or repository.

You mean you can do this (assuming there's a viewmodel for adding an order to a user and a `SaveChanges()` somewhere):

```
public class UserController
{
    public ActionResult AddUserOrder(AddUserOrderModel addOrder)
    {
        User user = User.GetByEmail(addOrder.UserEmail);        
        user.Orders.Add(addOrder.Order);
        User.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And especially that you can do `user.Orders.Add(...)`, then that's a side effect of exposing entity types from your service or repository layer.

If you want to avoid that, you'd have to define and expose a business object containing the members you want to expose:

```
public class UserBLL
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get { return _orders.AsEnumerable(); } }
    private IEnumerable<Order> _orders;

    public UserBLL(User user)
    {
        Id = user.Id;
        _orders = user.Orders;          
    }

    public void AddOrder(Order order)
    {
        _orders.Add(order);
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly,I thought also viewmodel. But I wasn't sure it may bring more complexity or not. I'll use viewmodels if I have to. Thanks.

Comment: The point is not the viewmodel, really. It's the BLL or Domain Model. An objects that represents your use case (a User that can have Orders). Use that if you don't want to expose your Data Models with their innards exposed.

Comment: Why you are returning `_orders.AsEnumerable();` while `_orders` is already `IEnumerable<Order>` ?

Comment: @Mohamed you're right, that's the wrong method. I wanted to return a collection that the user of the class cannot modify(one can through casting it to `ICollection<Order>`). It should probably be [`.ToList()` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285323/best-practice-how-to-expose-a-read-only-icollection), so the user gets a copy of the orders.

Answer (score 2):

There's not a real choice here. `ICollection` is needed by EF to control some of it's aspects like binding query results and lazy loading. By using `IEnumerable`, you're essentially turning all this functionality off, but along with it, EF's understanding of your underlying structure. When you generate migrations, EF will not generate any requisite underlying join tables for M2M relationships, foreign keys on related tables, etc.

Long and short, use `ICollection`. While you're correct that this allows you to add items by simply adding them to the collection on a related entity, sans-DAL, they still can't be *saved* without access to the context. If you've set up your DAL correctly, that's only available through the DAL, itself, so you still have to pass the entity back into your DAL pipeline to perpetuate any of these changes. In other words, don't worry about it.

Comment: I'm using IOC. Context shared by per request. In same request if I comitted it for another purpose, it may be affect. But you are right I think I don't have any action which select relational query then save or edit on same request. If I have I will use viewmodel which @CodeCaster told.